# Swipe a table cell to get two options

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swipe

I'm stuck on this bit because there is some information scattered all over, but never a solid explanation.

I've got a table view, filled with cells and sections. I'd like to see when I swipe on a cell (to the right), I get two buttons: 'Accept' and 'Reject'.

I've gotten as far as seeing the delete button. This only occurs anything but the first cell on each section (here, the program just detects `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`), and I've got no clue on how getting a second button in the cell, let alone editing those buttons.

Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to subclass UITableViewCell and add a GestureRecognizer in order to get this effect. The standard table editing functionality won't quite cut it here. The open source [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController) does something similar in its ELCAssetCell.m that ought to get you moving in the right direction:

```
[elcAsset addGestureRecognizer:[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:elcAsset action:@selector(toggleSelection)] autorelease]];
```

Comment: I am experimenting with it right now. Seems to me the whole customCell thing has to be redesigned, having optional buttons and labels for the swiping. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I'm editting your comment to explain more on how I did it.